# Comparing elements in a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, queue

I have a queue implementation as shown below.

```
static String a = "1 0 2014/03/03 01:34:39 0.0 0.0 0.0";
static String b = "2 1 2014/03/03 01:34:40 0.0 0.0 0.0";
static String c = "3 2 2014/03/03 01:34:41 0.0 0.0 0.0";
static String[] d;
String e;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Queue<String> s = new LinkedList<String>();
    s.add(a);
    s.add(b);
    s.add(c);
    }
```

As you see each entry in the list is a string with 7 elements. I would like to compare these entries from each string. For example the first entries from a, b, c using s.

Comment: And the question is?\

Comment: *I would like to compare these entries from each string* please explain how would you want to compare them.

Comment: I dont quite get the question AlllsWell.  Are you wanting us to write a compare method for you or something?  What have *you* done

Comment: You might try creating a custom class for your strings and implementing the `Comparable` interface. Then you could write your own `compareTo` method.

Comment: @Fallenreaper hi, nope. I would like to learn using new methods. if you see 1 2 3 in each string or different date entries.  I am not well aware of how to get these elements for comparison. My queue size will be growing not just three objects. I tried d = s.element().split(" "); which gave me just elements of first object.

Comment: @ElliotSchmelliot Hi thanks for getting back. Could you please give me an example. I not that good in java

Comment: if `S` is a queue, then if you are comparing them, how would that result be output to you?  Would you be reordering the Queue, would you make a new Queue?  What are you comparing on, given that you want to use S.

It seems like you want to get a Node from `S` and then compare to another node, which can be done similarly to how @ElliotSchmelliot had written.

I Personally would define a class for the data. and then write a compare function that would compare 2 Objects together and then output 1,0,-1 depending on the result of the comparison

Comment: TL:DR; thats exactly what @ElliotSchmelliot did. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an explanation of my comment, "Try creating a custom class for your strings and implementing the `Comparable` interface. Then you could write your own `compareTo` method."

Seeing as you have a very particular data type, you might create your own defined class. The following `MyString` class encapsulates a String, implements the `Comparable` interface, and provides an example of how you might use a `compareTo` method for such a class.

```
public class MyString implements Comparable<MyString> {
    private String data;

    public MyString(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public int compareTo(MyString other) {
        String[] thisArray = new String[6];
        String[] otherArray = new String[6];
        thisArray = this.data.split(" ");
        otherArray = other.data.split(" ");

        // Compare each pair of values in an order of your choice
        // Here I am only comparing the first two number values
        if (!thisArray[0].equals(otherArray[0])) {
            return thisArray[0].compareTo(otherArray[0]);
        } else if (!thisArray[1].equals(otherArray[1])){
            return thisArray[1].compareTo(otherArray[1]);
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The `compareTo` method returns 1, 0, or -1 depending on whether value A is respectively greater than, equal to, or lesser than value B. Again, this is just an example and I am only comparing Strings. Here is an example of how you might compare two of your formatted Strings using this method:

```
MyString a = new MyString("1 0 2014/03/03 01:34:39 0.0 0.0 0.0");
MyString b = new MyString("1 1 2014/03/03 01:34:40 0.0 0.0 0.0");
// Do something with the compared value, in this case -1
System.out.println(a.compareTo(b));
```

Documentation on `Comparable` and `compareTo` can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).